# Stack level too deep in Ruby array vs hash test

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap, benchmarking

Here is my script

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'ostruct'

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  n=10000
  array = n.times.map{ |i| OpenStruct.new id: i }
  hash = Hash[*(array.map{ |s| [s.id, s] }.flatten)]

  x.report('array') do
    array.find{ |s| s.id == 100}
  end
  x.report('hash') do
    hash[100]
  end
end
```

why with `n=100000` I get:

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

?

not related, but, am I building the hash in the best way?

Comment: hash lookup is always faster than `Array.find`, and `OpenStruct` is not the right thing to use as it uses `method_missing` to build its attributes

Comment: @bjhaid I don’t think any benchmark is necessarily “dumb”. What better way for someone to find out and prove to themselves that a Hash lookup is faster?

Comment: what would be the right thing?

Comment: @juanpastas You could use a simple [`Struct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Struct.html) instead.

Comment: oh ok, this code was for replicating some other thing I am working on, where I was adding properties, I will take this into account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You’re passing tens of thousands of arguments to a method and that’s just too many for Ruby to handle, causing a stack error.

Instead just pass the un-flattened, un-splatted mapped array to `Hash.[]`, since it accepts that just fine and gives the same (correct) result (without a SystemStackError):

```
Hash[array.map { |s| [s.id, s] }]
```

---

As an aside, we can see the argument count is in fact the issue (rather than specifically `Hash.[]`) with a simple test:

```
def f(*args); end
f(*(1..1000000).to_a)  #<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>
```